# Android ListView does not populate

Tags: firebase, android-studio, android-fragments, android-listview

I have two buttons on `fragment`, one button to show a `listview` using `SQLite` and the other button to show a `listview` using `Firebase`. The `listview` with `SQLite` works, but, although the logic is same, the `listview` with `Firebase` does not work. I could successfully retrieve data from `firebase` (I tested it using `Toast`, and it works just fine), but somehow, I just cannot display the retrieved data in `listview`.

Here is the entire codes of the fragment, including both `listview` for `SQLite` and `Firebase`:

```
package com.example.dailybible3;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction;

import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class FragmentNotes extends Fragment {

    private static final String TAG = "";
    private View view;
    private Button btn_all_notes, btn_my_notes;
    DatabaseHelper mDatabaseHelper;
    private ListView mListView;
    ListAdapter adapter;
    ArrayList<String> listData, listData2;

    public static FragmentNotes newInstance() {
        FragmentNotes fragmentNotes = new FragmentNotes();
        return fragmentNotes;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_notes, container, false);

        //SQL
        mListView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_view);
        mDatabaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(getActivity());

        populatePrivateListView();

        //all note button
        btn_all_notes = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_all_notes);
        btn_all_notes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                populatePublicListView();
            }
        });

        //my note button
        btn_my_notes = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_my_notes);
        btn_my_notes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                populatePrivateListView();
            }
        });

        //floating button
        FloatingActionButton fab = view.findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), MyNotes.class));
            }
        });

        return view;
    }


    private void populatePrivateListView() {
        Log.d(TAG, "populatePrivateListView: Displaying PRIVATE data in the ListView.");

        //get the data and append to a list
        Cursor cursor = mDatabaseHelper.getData();
        listData = new ArrayList<>();

        while(cursor.moveToNext()){
            //get the value from the database in column 1
            //then add it to the ArrayList
            listData.add(cursor.getString(1));
        }

        //create the list adapter and set the adapter
        //customize the listview with "list_view_item"
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(),R.layout.list_view_items, listData);
        mListView.setAdapter(adapter);

        //set an onItemClickListener to the ListView
        mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                String name = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
                Log.d(TAG, "onItemClick: You Clicked on " + name);

                Cursor data = mDatabaseHelper.getItemID(name); //get the id associated with that name
                int itemID = -1;
                while(data.moveToNext()){
                    itemID = data.getInt(0);
                }
                if(itemID > -1){
                    Log.d(TAG, "onItemClick: The ID is: " + itemID);
                    Intent editPrivateData  = new Intent(getActivity(), FragmentNotesEditPrivateData.class);
                    editPrivateData.putExtra("id", itemID);
                    editPrivateData.putExtra("name", name);
                    startActivity(editPrivateData);

                }
                else{
                    toastMessage("No ID associated with that name");
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void populatePublicListView() {
        DatabaseReference firebase;

        firebase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Note");

        //set the listview
        listData2 = new ArrayList<>();

        firebase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                String note = snapshot.getValue().toString();
                listData2.add(note);
                toastMessage(note);
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });

        //set the listview
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(),R.layout.list_view_items, listData2);
        mListView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    /**
     * customizable toast
     * @param message
     */
    private void toastMessage(String message){
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not working because your "adapter" can be null or undefined in certain cases and that's probably what's happening with you. To solve this, you need to keep in mind that a listener's job is to listen to your code. So, your

```
String note = snapshot.getValue().toString();
                listData2.add(note);
                toastMessage(note);
```

is implemented only when the listener detects a change in snapshot. I haven't personally implemented your code or tested it so can't tell about more loopholes. But one solution that I can immediately think of is something like this(Not exactly). You may have to play around and make listData2 static or put adapter outside the Listener to avoid memory leaks though. Try and let me know if it works.

```
  firebase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                    String note = snapshot.getValue().toString();
                    listData2.add(note);
                    toastMessage(note);
                    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(),R.layout.list_view_items, listData2);
                    mListView.setAdapter(adapter);
                }
                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
    
                }
            });
    
            //set the listview
```